# QT QPushButton Press Event

Tags: c++, qt, events

i want to do a very time-consuming operation when press a QT button but failed, can anybody help me explain this? thanks!
the code is:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (target == ui.zoominBtn){
         if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress){
             phcs[curPhcId].zoom(0.1);
             renderRaytracingImage();
         }
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(target, event);
}
```

now i move the time consuming-part to a QThread:

```
if (target == ui.zoominBtn){
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress){
        //phcs[curPhcId].zoom(0.1);
        TracerayThread *traceThread = new TracerayThread(&scene,&(phcs[curPhcId]),this);
        connect(traceThread, SIGNAL(resultReady()), this, SLOT(render()));
        connect(traceThread, SIGNAL(finished()), traceThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
        traceThread->start();
    }
}
```

i need to pass two pointer to the new thread,can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QPushButton click signal.

```
connect(YourButtonName,  &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::YourSlotName);
```

No need to use eventFilter. if you want to use it don't forget `installEventFilter`

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work either.i use a new thread to do the work but get nothing. can i pass a pointer in main-thread to a new QThread?

Comment: @redips you can use signals & slots to pass data from one thread to another.